# Why can I not see both effects in action?

Tags: adobe-after-effects, effects

I'm New to After Effects. Here's my composition:

1. Add Solid
2. Add "Fractal Noise" to Solid. Name is "Fractal Noise 1"
3. Add second "Fractal Noise" to solid. Name is "Fractal Noise 2"
4. Change "Fractal Noise 1" Fractal Type property to be "Dynamic Twist"
5. Look at preview screen I **see no** change in pattern
6. Change "Fractal Noise 2" Fractal Type property to be "Dynamic Twist"
7. Look at preview screen I **see a** change in pattern

My question is why does this behaviour occur? In my mind layers are put on top of each other so I'm thinking "Fractal Noise 1" should sit above "Fractal Noise 2". So this would mean that "Fractal Noise 1" should have any changes in its property reflected in the preview instead of it's current behaviour being hidden by "Fractal Noise 2".

See Images:
[image: "Fractal Noise 1" layer changed, but not for "Fractal Noise 2". No change seen on preview]
[image: "Fractal Noise 2" layer changed and now we do see a change on the preview]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Layers are put on top of each other with most recent creation on top of earlier creations.

So, Fractal Noise 2 sits above Fractal Noise 1 this is why changes to Fractal Noise 1 do not show through Fractal Noise 2.

Changing the "property" of a layer does not change it's relative position in the layer stack.